Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS repo problem
Just installed my new Ubuntu Server and got this error, pls help.
legal@legalposition:~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:1 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:1 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:4 https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Ign:4 https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:4 https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Err:1 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 91.189.91.39 443]
Err:2 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 91.189.91.39 443]
Err:3 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 91.189.91.39 443]
Err:4 https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.91.14). - connect (113: No route to host)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 91.189.91.39 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 91.189.91.39 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 91.189.91.39 443]
W: Failed to fetch https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.91.14). - connect (113: No route to host)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
legal@legalposition:~$

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

what do you get when you type: lsb_release -a

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

There is no effective HTTPS on the round-robin URLs like archive.ubuntu.com and others. That's why you're getting the errors you're getting.  Edit your sources to use http:// instead of https://.  This is a known issue with the repositories but because the repos use a number of different mirrors with different hosts, etc. the certificates don't match up properly for the Ubuntu hostnames and you get the errors you see.

This question is similar to: How do I restore the default repositories?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@karel I don't believe that question is a duplicate of this one, however, I see it as (part of) the answer to this one and the main part of the answer is ThomasWard's comment.

@Dan Please find a better duplicate question.
